# How to replace TypeParameter from TypeNode using typescript compiler

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am processing  members of a class and would like to replace occurrences of O with string.

Input :

```
class Sample {
  sn<O extends string>(input:{ one: O, twO : {k : O} ,three:O[] }) {
  }
}
```

Processing Example:

```
methods.map(m => {
        const n = m.name.getText();
        const params = m.parameters
        const pl = params.length;
        let payload = ""
        if (pl === 1) {
            payload = params[0].type!.getText() //{one: O, two : {k : O},three:O[] })
            if (m.typeParameters) { // if typeParams exist i want replace all occurence of TypeReference O with string
                const tp = m.typeParameters[0]
              payload = `{one: string, twO : {k : string},three:string[] })` // i want result like this
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

It's helpful in cases like these to study the AST structure of your code and refer to it as you build out your solution. You can analyze the AST using TypeScript AST Viewer.

[Here is what your code looks like](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKYFsAOICm0DeAoa0IDsAeAeWlQA8AXVfAExgkoCcBLfAcwD4AKNpAV0oAuDNAD2+VEOjEANNEoB3UtIwBraNOIBfaLMoALJqinEA2gF1o2gJSYc1rNqA)

You can see here that your `MethodDeclaration` has a `typeParameters` property, which is an array of `TypeParameter`. It also has `parameters`, which is an array of `Parameter`.

What you're looking to do is replace any `TypeReference` that occurs in any descendant of nodes in `parameters` which points to `O` with the corresponding `TypeParameter` `O`'s `constraint` property.

There are a couple of routes you can take for this. The easiest and most widely documented approach is to use a transformer.

#### Example Code

The following example will apply itself to all methods. It looks for `TypeReference` nodes anywhere in the `parameters` `NodeArray` and checks if it's a reference to one of the method's `TypeParameter`s. If it is, it will replace that reference with its constraint.

This is a bit broader than the your question, but I assumed your actual application may be closer to this. If not, you should be able to easily modify it to target specific methods or parameter names.

Hopefully this will help point you in the right direction

Try the code on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-transformer-example?file=index.ts

```
import * as ts from 'typescript'
import { Node, SourceFile } from 'typescript'


/* ****************************************************************************************************************** *
 * Code to transform
 * ****************************************************************************************************************** */

const cls = `
class Sample {
  sn<O extends string>(input:{ one: O, twO : {k : O} ,three:O[] }) {
  }
}
`;


/* ****************************************************************************************************************** *
 * Transformer
 * ****************************************************************************************************************** */

const transformer = (ctx: ts.TransformationContext) => (sourceFile: SourceFile): SourceFile => {
    function paramVisitor(baseMethod: ts.MethodDeclaration) {
        return (node: Node): Node => {
            if (ts.isTypeReferenceNode(node)) {
                const typeParam = baseMethod.typeParameters.find(t => t.name.escapedText === (node.typeName as ts.Identifier).escapedText);
                if (typeParam) return typeParam.constraint;
            }

            return ts.visitEachChild(node, paramVisitor(baseMethod), ctx);
        };
    }

    const visit = (node: Node): Node => {
        if (ts.isMethodDeclaration(node))
            return ts.updateMethod(
                node,
                node.decorators,
                node.modifiers,
                node.asteriskToken,
                node.name,
                node.questionToken,
                node.typeParameters,
                ts.visitNodes(node.parameters, paramVisitor(node)),
                node.type,
                node.body
            );

        return ts.visitEachChild(node, visit, ctx);
    };

    return ts.visitNode(sourceFile, visit);
};


/* ****************************************************************************************************************** *
 * Demonstration
 * ****************************************************************************************************************** */

const s = ts.createSourceFile('example.ts', cls, ts.ScriptTarget.ES5);
const { transformed } = ts.transform(s, [ transformer ]);

console.log(ts.createPrinter().printFile(transformed.find(f => f.fileName === 'example.ts')));
```

#### Recommended reading:

[How to Write a TypeScript Transform (Plugin)](https://dev.doctorevidence.com/how-to-write-a-typescript-transform-plugin-fc5308fdd943)

[Creating a TypeScript Transformer](https://43081j.com/2018/08/creating-a-typescript-transform?source=post_page-----731e2b0b66e6----------------------)

#### Recommended tools:

[ts-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@phenomnomnominal/tsquery) - For a more surgical approach

[ts-morph](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph) - Can help make compiler API work easier.

[ts-patch](https://github.com/dsherret/ts-morph) - If you need to apply transformers during tsc compilation

#### PS

In the future, add the tag [typescript-compiler-api](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/typescript-compiler-api) to your posts. These types of questions have a much better chance of being answered with that tag.